# Where can I learn to set up an email sending environment with all authentication?

Tags: email, authentication

I have a client that would like to start sending their own email (vs using a third party email service provider like MailChimp) and they have asked me to help with the setup process.

Are there are any courses that teach how to set up high volume email sending environments including the required authentication.

From what I have been able to find, I know that I will need a server with a static IP adress, possibly SSL, and that I will need to set up SPF, SenderID, DKIM, Domain Keys and also set up bounce management.

I know these things in theory, but practically I don't know how to execute and would love to learn how to do these things, as it would prove valuable for future clients.

Thank you in advance.